# Correctly indent code with Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

Can Notepad++ correctly indent code?

If I had this:

```
<div><div><div></div></div>   </div>
```

Is there a way of turning it into the following?

```
<div>
  <div>
    <div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is asking about reindenting - if it was changing the behaviour when pressing Enter (auto indent), it would be the checkbox in menu *Settings* → *Preferences* → *MISC.* → *Auto Indent*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use TextFX plugin to reindent code for you. If you don't have it, you will need to install in from your plugin manager. Once in place > just use the menu "TextFX" > "TextFX Edit" > "Reindent C++ code".

Probably it won't convert a single line, but actual code with miss-indentations will be handled well.

You will find more info and other plugins explained [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/412427/auto-indent-in-notepad).

Comment: The OP asked about HTML, not about C++

Comment: And just to be doubly clear: the "Reindent C++ code" action does not indent my HTML code (N++ v6.5.1)

Comment: @Imray Really? You don't say.

Comment: @Daryn At the time of writing (1 year ago) this was working.

Comment: @Magnum I hear you. That's why I added version number, I know these things change over time.

Comment: Observed today: TextFX plugin isn't available for 64-bit NPP.

Answer (score 4):

Install *Indent by Fold* plugin. It works well with XML (or, derivatives) tags.

Comment: Tried it...nothing happened. :(

Answer (score 0):

All of my code was on a single line ([minified](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_(programming))). What I did was use an online "unminifier" to bust up the code into multiple lines. There are many available if you [search Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=unminify), but here's the one that worked best for me:
http://mrcoles.com/blog/css-unminify/

I, then, used the plugin [@Magnum mentioned](https://superuser.com/a/557618/455788) ([TextFX](https://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/TextFX/)) to dress up the indents in the code further. The result was great!

Before:

```
object(stdClass)#2 (1) { ["GetDocTypeListResult"]=> object(stdClass)#3 (1) { ["DocType"]=> array(14) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#4 (2) { ["id"]=> string(3) "180" ["name"]=> string(49) "Return Merchandise Authorization and Notification" } [1]=> object(stdClass)#5 (2) { ["id"]=> string(3) "810" ["name"]=> string(16) "Customer Invoice" } [2]=> object(stdClass)#6 (2) { ["id"]=> string(3) "816" ["name"]=> string(28) "Organizational Relationships" } [3]=> object(stdClass)#7 (2) { ["id"]=> string(3) "820" ["name"]=> string(31) "Payment Order Remittance Advice" } [4]=> object(stdClass)#8 (2) { ["id"]=> string(3) "824" ["name"]=> string(18) "Application Advice" } [5]=> object(stdClass)#9 (2) { ["id"]=> string(3) "830" ["name"]=> string(41) "Planning Schedule with Release Capability" } [6]=> object(stdClass)#10 (2) { ["id"]=> string(3) "840" ["name"]=> string(21) "Request for Quotation" } [7]=> object(stdClass)#11 (2) { ["id"]=> string(3) "846" ["name"]=> string(24) "Inventory Inquiry/Advice" } [8]=> object(stdClass)#12 (2) { ["id"]=> string(3) "850" ["name"]=> string(14) "Purchase Order" } [9]=> object(stdClass)#13 (2) { ["id"]=> string(3) "852" ["name"]=> string(21) "Product Activity Data" } [10]=> object(stdClass)#14 (2) { ["id"]=> string(3) "860" ["name"]=> string(47) "Purchase Order Change Request - Buyer Initiated" } [11]=> object(stdClass)#15 (2) { ["id"]=> string(3) "864" ["name"]=> string(12) "Text Message" } [12]=> object(stdClass)#16 (2) { ["id"]=> string(3) "945" ["name"]=> string(25) "Warehouse Shipping Advice" } [13]=> object(stdClass)#17 (2) { ["id"]=> string(3) "997" ["name"]=> string(26) "Functional Acknowledgement" } } } }
```

After:

```
object(stdClass)#2 (1)  {
    ["GetDocTypeListResult"]=> object(stdClass)#3 (1)  {
        ["DocType"]=> array(14)  {
            [0]=> object(stdClass)#4 (2)  {
                ["id"]=> string(3) "180" 
                ["name"]=> string(49) "Return Merchandise Authorization and Notification" }
            [1]=> object(stdClass)#5 (2)  {
                ["id"]=> string(3) "810" 
                ["name"]=> string(16) "Customer Invoice" }
            [2]=> object(stdClass)#6 (2)  {
                ["id"]=> string(3) "816" 
                ["name"]=> string(28) "Organizational Relationships" }
            [3]=> object(stdClass)#7 (2)  {
                ["id"]=> string(3) "820" 
                ["name"]=> string(31) "Payment Order Remittance Advice" }
            [4]=> object(stdClass)#8 (2)  {
                ["id"]=> string(3) "824" 
                ["name"]=> string(18) "Application Advice" }
            [5]=> object(stdClass)#9 (2)  {
                ["id"]=> string(3) "830" 
                ["name"]=> string(41) "Planning Schedule with Release Capability" }
            [6]=> object(stdClass)#10 (2)  {
                ["id"]=> string(3) "840" 
                ["name"]=> string(21) "Request for Quotation" }
            [7]=> object(stdClass)#11 (2)  {
                ["id"]=> string(3) "846" 
                ["name"]=> string(24) "Inventory Inquiry/Advice" }
            [8]=> object(stdClass)#12 (2)  {
                ["id"]=> string(3) "850" 
                ["name"]=> string(14) "Purchase Order" }
            [9]=> object(stdClass)#13 (2)  {
                ["id"]=> string(3) "852" 
                ["name"]=> string(21) "Product Activity Data" }
            [10]=> object(stdClass)#14 (2)  {
                ["id"]=> string(3) "860" 
                ["name"]=> string(47) "Purchase Order Change Request - Buyer Initiated" }
            [11]=> object(stdClass)#15 (2)  {
                ["id"]=> string(3) "864" 
                ["name"]=> string(12) "Text Message" }
            [12]=> object(stdClass)#16 (2)  {
                ["id"]=> string(3) "945" 
                ["name"]=> string(25) "Warehouse Shipping Advice" }
            [13]=> object(stdClass)#17 (2)  {
                ["id"]=> string(3) "997" 
                ["name"]=> string(26) "Functional Acknowledgement" }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The [Tidy2](http://code.google.com/p/npp-tidy2/) plugin does exactly what you want.

Comment: Can you add more information?

Comment: A link to developer's/distributor's website and some detail on plugin would be helpful

Comment: All this did was wrap the code in an HTML body tag. :(